# One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined Error in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, dropbox

I'm facing issue while using my own Framework .**One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.** I know this issue already posted on Stackoverflow but this one is different.

I Created my own Framework and Integrate Dropbox with my framework which fine but I need to use my own framework into app let say **SDKTestProject**. So there is some code which I need to write in App delegate like following code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController.photoViewController animated:YES];
        }
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

So I decided to added DropboxSDK Framework from just Reference in my Framework like in following image because if I add Dropbox in my Framework then in App (which consume my app) will not access dropbox because there is no file of dropboxsdk in umbrella file.

[image]

Mentioned its path in **Framework Search Path** and **-ObjC** in **Other linker flag** that all in My Framework

Now I added my framework into my app and then added dropboxsdk framework in my app too. Its all looking fine but I'm facing warning **Class DBAccountInfo is implemented in both** `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B25F7188-D27F-4DBD-BA2F-843214BA94E2/SDKTestProject.app/Frameworks/SigningHubSDK.framework/SigningHubSDK (0x10066c290) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/B25F7188-D27F-4DBD-BA2F-843214BA94E2/SDKTestProject.app/SDKTestProject (0x10003fd18)`

**One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.** And dropbox isn't working.

I didn't added dropboxsdk framework into my own framework just reference connect but added dropboxsdk in app. So where I need suggestion where I'm doing and what should I do in my scenario is there any alternative approach.

Comment: any one found the solution of this problem?